# C++ getArea() and cout not working

Tags: c++, eclipse

This is my code, I am relatively new to C++. The only other C++ program that I've ever written was an atm app. For this project, I'm trying to find the area of a box, any suggestions n why this isn't working?

Anyways heres my code

```
/*
 * c.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 31, 2014
 *      Author: University of Denver. Yeah, I smoke weed.
 */

class Box
{
   public:
      // pure virtual function
      virtual double getVolume() = 0;
   private:
      double length;      // Length of a box
      double breadth;     // Breadth of a box
      double height;      // Height of a box
};

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Base class
class Shape 
{
public:
   // pure virtual function providing interface framework.
   virtual int getArea() = 0;
   void setWidth(int w)
   {
      width = w;
   }
   void setHeight(int h)
   {
      height = h;
   }
protected:
   int width;
   int height;
};

// Derived classes
class Rectangle: public Shape
{
public:
   int getArea()
   { 
      return (width * height); 
   }
};
class Triangle: public Shape
{
public:
   int getArea()
   { 
      return (width * height)/2; 
   }
};

int main(void)
{
   Rectangle Rect;
   Triangle  Tri;

   Rect.setWidth(5);
   Rect.setHeight(7);
   // Print the area of the object.
   cout << "Total Rectangle area: " << Rect.getArea() << endl;

   Tri.setWidth(5);
   Tri.setHeight(7);
   // Print the area of the object.
   cout << "Total Triangle area: " << Tri.getArea() << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting when you run it?

Comment: You're going to have to tell us what isn't working, where in the code it isn't working, and what you expect to see.

Comment: When I click Run in Eclipse, I get an prompt that says "Launch failed. Binary not found."

Comment: I got 2 results 35 and 17. What is the problem?

Comment: have you build it first ?

Comment: Im trying to compile it but its not working.

Comment: Im getting an error, that says "Invalid path not found" These area all eclispe generated includes.

Comment: Try using a different IDE, QtCreator is very good in general (you don't have to create Qt projects in it) or maybe VS2013 express.

Answer (score 0):

The code is valid compiled and outputs 35 and 17. I think the problem is that your console window is closed quickly by the system and you do not see the result. You can insert any command that will wait until you enter something as for example

```
int i;

std::cin >> i;
```

or something similar before the return

If you use MS VC++ you can run console applications with key combination Ctrl + F5

Also take into account that your class Box is not used and may be removed.